# Find element in array and return parent

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I'm having an issue trying to get parent element of found element in array.

This is my array for example:

```
const arr = [
  {
    name: 'first level',
    selected: true,
    subItems: [
      {
        name: 'second level 1',
        selected: false,
        subItems: [],
      },
      {
        name: 'second level 2',
        selected: true,
        subItems: [
          {
            name: 'third level 1',
            selected: false,
            subItems: [],
          },
          {
            name: 'third level 2',
            selected: false,
            subItems: [],
          },
          {
            name: 'third level 3',
            selected: false,
            subItems: [],
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        name: 'second level 3',
        selected: false,
        subItems: [
          {
            name: 'third level 4',
            selected: false,
            subItems: []
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
];
```

So basically if key **selected** is true I would like to return it's parent element. Now I don't know how deep can this array be, so I have taken recursive approach to the problem.

```
const getParent = (items, parentCat = null) => {
    if (items && items.length > 0) {
        const selectedCat = items.find(item => item.selected === true);
        if (selectedCat && selectedCat.subItems.length > 0) {
          return getParent(selectedCat.subItems, selectedCat);
        }
        return parentCat;
    }
};

const parent = getParent(arr);
```

But the code will only work in some cases when there are not subItems for the selected item. I would like to get parent item of deepest selected element.

EDIT: If any element has selected true, also it's parent will have true, also there will always be just one selected element per level.

Comment: Can we assume that you can't have a selected node without the parent also being selected?

Comment: And if a third level element was selected, would you expect a second level parent element to be returned? Or should it cascade all the way up to a first level parent?

Comment: Please show what output structure you get currently and what it should look like.

Comment: @jack This is way I get the data, in third level I could get subItems with no data just an empty array. Yes parent will always be selected.

Comment: So you want to get the deepest `selected` item in the chain of selection?

Comment: @Barmar Yes, I want parent element of deepest selected item.

Comment: What should be the correct result with the sample data? `second level 2` or `first level`?

Comment: @Barmar First level, but if third level had item with selected true then it should be second level.

Comment: @3limin4t0r  That would always get me the first level of selected item, but what If I am on third level and it has no subItems and it that case I would like the parent element.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that within the recursion, if none of the items are selected, you must return the parent's parent. You can accomplish that by returning `null` within the deepest recursion, and let the caller handle it as the stack unwinds.

```
const getParent = (items, parent = null) => {
    const selectedItem = items.find(item => item.selected === true);
    if (selectedItem) {
        // if there was a deeper parent, return that
        // otherwise return my own parent
        return getParent(selectedItem.subItems, selectedItem) || parent;
    } else {
        return null;
    }
};
```

```js
const arr = [
  {
    name: 'first level',
    selected: true,
    subItems: [
      {
        name: 'second level 1',
        selected: false,
        subItems: [],
      },
      {
        name: 'second level 2',
        selected: true,
        subItems: [
          {
            name: 'third level 1',
            selected: false,
            subItems: [],
          },
          {
            name: 'third level 2',
            selected: false,
            subItems: [],
          },
          {
            name: 'third level 3',
            selected: false,
            subItems: [],
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        name: 'second level 3',
        selected: false,
        subItems: [
          {
            name: 'third level 4',
            selected: false,
            subItems: []
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
];

const getParent = (items, parent = null) => {
    const selectedItem = items.find(item => item.selected === true);
    if (selectedItem) {
        return getParent(selectedItem.subItems, selectedItem) || parent;
    } else {
        return null;
    }
};

console.log(getParent(arr));
```

Comment: `item.selected === true` could be replaced by `item.selected` if a truthy or falsy value suffices.